# Как скрыть форму в трей только при закрытии (крестиком)

Tags: c#

```
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {            
        save_data();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        e.Cancel = true;           
    }
```

Так работает. Но когда мне нужно реально закрыть окно с кнопки или через меню, то вызывается та же функция, что приведена выше, и окно сворачивается.
Как нужно прописать условие, чтобы проверить, что окно закрывается крестиком. Видимо как-то так:

```
if (sender (...) == крестик на форме) e.Cancel = true;
```

Подскажите как правильно прописать это условие :)

Comment: просто введите какое-то булевое значение, например `MinimizeToTrayOnClosing`, сделайте её по-умолчанию `true`, а при нажатии на кнопку, перед тем как вызвать `form.Close()`, установите переменную равной `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всегда интересуйтесь что за аргументы `FormClosingEventArgs` у обработчика события. У разных обработчиков они разные бывают. В них обычно много полезного.

```cs
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
        save_data();
        this.Hide(); // чтобы обратно показать, используйте this.Show();
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: отлично, спасибо. Хотя CloseReason.UserClosing распространяется не только на "крестик", но и на любую команду this.Close() в коде. Но вопрос решается, если в том случае, когда программу надо закрыть использовать Application.Exit(). И тогда все работает как надо